# How to retrieve attributes of xml tag in Python?

Tags: python, xml, tags

I'm looking for a way to add attributes to xml tags in python. Or to create a new tag with a new attributes 
for example, I have the following xml file:

```
<types name='character' shortName='chrs'>
....
...

</types>
```

and i want to add an attribute to make it look like this:

```
<types name='character' shortName='chrs' fullName='MayaCharacters'>
....
...
</types>
```

how do I do that with python? by the way. I use python and minidom for this
please help. thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [attributes](http://docs.python.org/library/xml.dom.html#xml.dom.Node.attributes) property of the respective `Node` object.

For example:

```
from xml.dom.minidom import parseString
documentNode = parseString("<types name='character' shortName='chrs'></types>")
typesNode = documentNode.firstChild

# Getting an attribute
print typesNode.attributes["name"].value # will print "character"

# Setting an attribute
typesNode.attributes["mynewattribute"] = u"mynewvalue"
print documentNode.toprettyxml()
```

The last `print` statement will output this XML document:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<types mynewattribute="mynewvalue" name="character" shortName="chrs"/>
```

Comment: +1 i like your way in simplifying things . dude you should start writing books !

Answer (score 1):

I learned xml parsing in python from [this great article](http://www.boddie.org.uk/python/XML_intro.html). It has an attribute section, which cant be linked to, but just search for "*Attributes*" on that page and you'll find it, that holds the information you need.

But in short (snippet stolen from said page):

```
>>> building_element.setAttributeNS("http://www.boddie.org.uk/paul/business", "business:name", "Ivory Tower")
>>> building_element.getAttributeNS("http://www.boddie.org.uk/paul/business", "name")
'Ivory Tower'
```

You probably want to skip the handling of namespaces, to make the code cleaner, unless you need them.

Answer (score 0):

It would seem that you just call `setAttribute` for the parsed dom objects.

http://developer.taboca.com/cases/en/creating_a_new_xml_document_with_python/